# Generation of pseudo-absences with R Biomod2

Tags: r, biostatistics

I have started working in species distribution and I'm not at ease on the subject yet. I'm using `biomod2` package in R, with several rasters to apply to species with presence-only data. My aim it to generate a pseudoabsence model. I tried to follow tutorials but they're not usable for me (either not clear or relying on input data frames that cannot be accessed). I'll thus also accept suggestions for good tutorials.

I have, for now:

1) generated the explanatory model:

```
myExpl = stack(Raster_vaud_srad1,
    Raster_vaud_srad2,
    Raster_vaud_srad3,
    Raster_vaud_srad4,
    Raster_vaud_srad5,
    Raster_vaud_srad6,
    Raster_vaud_srad7,
    Raster_vaud_srad8,
    Raster_vaud_srad9,
    Raster_vaud_srad10,
    Raster_vaud_srad11,
    Raster_vaud_srad12,
    Raster_vaud_slope,
    Raster_vaud_topos,
    Raster_vaud_topo,
    Raster_vaud_aspval,
    Raster_vaud_GDD_mod,
    Raster_vaud_mind_mod,
    layers=NULL)

    plot(myExpl)
```

2) extracted all the geographic dataset coordinates

```
 species_presence<-read.table(file.choose(),sep=";",dec=".",h=T)

    Y<-sample(c(30000:60000),100,replace=F)
    Y<-sample(c(70000:250000),100,replace=F)
    coordinates<-dataframe(x,y)# with te real data i used this code: na.omit(unic(prova_aquilegia[,c(4,5)]))
    Presence<-c(rep(1,length(X)))
    SpecNames<-"Species"
```

3) created the pseudoabsences

```
myBiomodData <- BIOMOD_FormatingData(resp.var = Presence, expl.var =
myExpl, resp.xy = coordinates, resp.name = SpecNames, PA.nb.rep= 1,
PA.nb.absences = 13414,  PA.strategy="random", PA.dist.min=200) ## for
PA.nb.absence I used the number of points of the rasters
```

Here is the error I get on step 3:

```
Error in sample.int(length(x), size, replace, prob) :    invalid first argument In addition: Warning
messages: 1: In if (nbTrueAbs >= nb.points) { :   the condition has
length > 1 and only the first element will be used 2: In if ((nb.repet
== 0 | nb.points <= 0) & strategy != "user.defined") { :   the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used 3: In
if (nb.cells <= nb.points) { :   the condition has length > 1 and only
the first element will be used
```

I expected to have generated the pseudoabsences but I start to think I may missing some steps.

I'll appreciate any input.

Cross-posted on: [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58504548/biomod2-generation-of-pseudo-absences)

Answer (score 0):

In case we found the problem. For people experimenting with the same issue, it is due to the rasters attributes which have to be null (interge=0) if you convert in .asc your raster you should not have that problem anymore.

Comment: Welcome to [stats.se].
Thank you for you answer. I think your post should be [edit]ed and improved to answer more clearly the question.
By the way, take the opportunity to take the [Tour], if you haven't done it already. See also some tips on [answer], on 
[formatting help](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/formatting)
and on writing down equations using 
[LaTeX / MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020).